# Microsoft Azure translation API only working after second translation attempt

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm writing a program that, as of right now, simply translates one word to a language of the users choice (written in swift). I'm using a cocoapod for this which is called TranslatorSwift (https://github.com/yokoe/TranslatorSwift)
This pod uses the Microsoft Azure text translation API to do its job. As of right now I have the following code within my viewcontroller:

```
  let testWord : String = "dog"
  @IBAction func onTranslateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    translator.translate(input: "\(testWord)", to: "es") { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let translation):
            self.outputLabel.text = translation
            print("\(translation)")
        case .failure(let error):
            self.outputLabel.text = "TRANSLATION FAILED"
            print(error.debugDescription)

        }
    }
```

After pressing onTranslateButton, I get "TRANSLATION FAILED" along with the following debugDescription in the console

```
Error Domain=TranslatorSwift.Translator.TranslationError Code=1 "(null)"
```

However, after pressing the button for a second time, I get a successful translation, indicated by the textfield within the app showing "perro" (Spanish for dog)

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening to me? Obviously the API is somewhat working, but just not on the initial translation attempt (regardless of how long I wait to press the button upon app startup)

Comment: The "(null)" in the message makes me wonder if the testWord variable has text in it on the first click. Based on the code you've provided I don't see any reason why it wouldn't but I would suggest doing a print(testWord) before the translator.translate call. Also you should be able to simply pass in testWord (since it's a string) instead of doing "\(testWord)"

Comment: Alright so I added `print(testWord)` to viewDidLoad and sure enough the console printed 'dog' no worries. Starting to think there may be an error in the cocoapod somewhere because I honestly just cant see an logical solution :/

Comment: You may want to try running Charles proxy to see what the request / response looks like. It may provide more information than the pod is providing. Or if you don't want to run a proxy, try taking the code from https://github.com/yokoe/TranslatorSwift/blob/master/TranslatorSwift/Classes/Translator.swift and running it directly in your application to see what the response is the first time. Maybe it will help uncover the issue. Unfortunately I don't have an account setup to try this myself. Good luck.